# UPDATE no actualiza registros PHP

Tags: php, mysql

He estado tratando de actualizar mi tabla usando PHP, la idea sería que si en dicha tabla hay dos ítem con el mismo código a pesar de que el campo cantidad sea diferente, que pueda eliminar uno de esos dos ítem, no los 2 al mismo tiempo, pero el problema que estoy teniendo es que la tabla no se actualiza, el código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";

if($codigo){
    include 'conexion.php';
    if($conexion){
        
        $consulta="update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=? limit 1";
        if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$consulta)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$codigo);
            var_dump($codigo);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $output="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
            }else{
                $output="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
            }    
        }else{
            $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
        
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        $output="No hay conexion";
    }
}else{
    $output="Codigo vacio o no valido";
}

echo $output;
?>
```

Cabe aclarar que si hago clic en uno de esos item (en app android) el estado cambia a 0, por ende no aparecería en el listado, aqui abajo adjunto captura de pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dices que no te esta actualizando?, en ese var_dump  te esta trayendo los datos enviados por post?

Comment: Exacto, no está actualizando, dice "Filas actualizadas 0"

Comment: Y si, ese var_dump trae los datos enviado por POST

Comment: Pon un echo "update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=$codigo limit 1" para ver que estas actualizando

Comment: Jorge Luis, puse  echo "update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=$codigo limit 1" y simplemente imprime "update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=$codigo limit 1"

Comment: Entonces prueba así "update agregados set estado=0 where codigo=".$codigo." limit 1" para asegurar que muestre el valor de codigo

Comment: JorgeLuis acabo de probar eso que me dices pero ahora me dice "Error ejecutando la consulta:

Comment: Si le pusiste el echo? porque si sale error codigo no es un string

Comment: Tu error esta en el ```if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$consulta)){``` antes del if estas haciendo una consulta preparada, luego estas diciendo que si esta consulta esta bien entra al if, pero en realidad nunca entrara al if ya que estas colocando valores en ? lo que indica que no esta encontrando nada, por ende no entra al bind_param chequea eso

Comment: En otras palabras, coloca ```mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$codigo);``` fuera del if, despues de ```$consulta```

Comment: @ernestojimenez lo que dices no es correcto, en las consultas preparadas se escribe siempre `?` porque precisamente la finalidad es poner marcadores para no poner directamente los valores, a fin de evitar la *Inyección SQL*. Por eso el  `if` lo que verifica es que la consulta se prepare sin problemas, como errores de sintaxis por ejemplo. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), allí hay ejemplos similares a este: `if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {`

Comment: El código parece correcto, la única cosa que haría que se comporte como dices es el valor de $codigo. Añade esa variable en `$output="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);` como `$output="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)." para el código: ".$codigo;` y comprueba que se esté comportando correctamente.

Comment: @DigiSoul Probé a agregar eso que tu dices, es decir $output="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)."Código: ".$codigo;, y dice "Filas actualizadas:0+codigo correspondiente del item que quiero actualizar"